# ASP.NET Call to API Endpoint returns 500 - Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, api, asp.net-web-api

I am calling a Rest API using a basic http authentication

```
  public string Get(string LabName)
    {
        string userName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
        string BaseURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL"];

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(  delegate { return true; });
            Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL);
            client.BaseAddress = uri;
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName+":"+password);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));


            string clarity_URL = BaseURL + "api/v2/labs?name=" + LabName;
            var response = client.GetAsync(clarity_URL).Result;

            string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return responseString;
        }
```

When I debug the code throws error on the line response like

[image]

Can anyone please suggest me what could be the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 500 Error usually means there is a problem with the API Server.

It would be a good idea to check the specific endpoint for any errors then check again with this code.

If you are checking against a web call that is working correctly, please ensure that the request method (GET / POST / PUT) is correctly aligned and the parameters match.

Comment: I am to access the API through the browser

Comment: I can access the API through the browser

Comment: Are you using different parameters perhaps?  Something may not be processing correctly within the endpoint.

Comment: Is the Endpoint a GET / PUT / POST, and are these in alignment with your web call?